# Laravel 9 Migration not creating Foreign Key

Tags: php, laravel

I just have a fresh Laravel 9 (latest) installation. I have made some migrations successfully and tried to add foreign key constraints, but Laravel's not creating the actual Foreign Key itself. It doesn't throw any errors and I can query everything just fine, but no Foreign key is being created.

What's strange is that I've simply copied the Migration code from one of my older projects. Here is the 2 migration Schema:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I do the migration I get an index called `posts_user_id_foreign` but no Foreign Key is being added.

I have already tried the following variations on the `Posts` table with no success:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
-----
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onUpdate('cascade');
-----
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening and what's the solution? I had no issues creating Foreign Key before with Laravel. Not sure what's changed now in the latest version...

Answer (score 0):

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

you can use ondelete cascade or restrict

Comment: Already tested that. And the onUpdate too, it's not working.

Comment: can you please send the error

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, there is no error. It's just not doing it. You can try by freshly installing Laravel and use my code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).